# Download a list of netCDF data from a text file using Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to download a some netCDF data from text file by python (google colab) but returns error. Does anyone has idea? The code and text file attached.

text file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c5ULjo-z2OyA_an5DVggsOv6heuVnbrW/view?usp=sharing

```
import requests

def download_file(url, destination):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f"File downloaded: {destination}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download file: {url}")

# Read the text file containing the URLs
file_path = 'prov.data_fetch+dGLDAS_CLSM025_D_2_0_GWS_tavg+t19800101000000_20131231235959.txt'
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    urls = file.readlines()

# Iterate over each URL and download the files
for url in urls:
    url = url.strip()  # Remove leading/trailing whitespaces
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]  # Extract the filename from the URL
    destination = f'/content/drive/MyDrive/test_data/{filename}'  # Specify the destination path
    download_file(url, destination)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example? Also, tell us what is actually throwing the error and the full traceback

Comment: The code only returns the second message: Failed to download file: {url}

Comment: Make life easier for us. Just give us a piece of code that runs out of the box.